# Reading specified lines count

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io

I've always programmed on C++ and Pascal and think too imperatively. So, could anyone help me with the question:

Consider we have the following input pattern:

```
integer n
n strings
other data
```

For example:

```
2
foo
bar
3 4
and so on.
```

So, I need to read only n Strings into a List, without reading other data. How should I do that without for-like constructions?

Comment: can you specify more - do you want to read n strings from commandline or file - there's a great tutorial of reading and handling files http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_IO_for_Imperative_Programmers

Comment: @epsilonhalbe From a commandline. Thanks for tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible method is

```
getLines n = sequence $ replicate n getLine
```

`getLine` is an IO action that reads a line from the standard input and returns it as a string. Its type is `IO String`.

`replicate n` creates a list of `n` identical items. So `replicate n getLine` is a list of `n` IO actions, each returning a string: `[IO String]`.

`sequence` is a function that takes a list of actions that return something, and turns it into a single action that returns a list of that something. So if we have an `[IO String]`, then `sequence` will turn it into `IO [String]`.

Which is just what we want.

Comment: You could also use `replicateM` as in `getLines n = replicateM n getLine`.

Comment: +1 i would have written (and have) this in a recursive function - the `sequence $ replicate n …` is much better, a thing to remember

Comment: @hammar: Thanks! Note to self: memorize contents of `Contol.Monad`.